# Hangup In A Simple Test C Program From Scanf to Printf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Putting the toes into the C programming and tried this test after another small program wasn't working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    printf("Test1\n");
    printf("Test2\n");
    printf("InputTest1: ");
    scanf("%d\n", i);
    printf("OutputTest1: %d\n", i);
    printf("InputTest2: ");
    scanf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Test1
Test2
InputTest1: 10

For some reason that I cannot surmise when going from scanf to printf it hangs and then doesn't print anymore.

Thank you for your assistance,

Comment: `scanf("%d", &i)`. `scanf` needs the address so it can update the variable.

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to pass a *pointer* to `i` to `scanf()`, not `i` itself (C doesn't have arguments by reference). But `scanf()` is fraught with problems for user input and it would be better to use `fgets()` and convert the number using `strtol()`.